# Is it possible to select a whole word in PhpStorm when ctrl-clicking on it?

Tags: phpstorm

Back in the old days when I was using EditPlus, I could ctrl-click on a word, and the whole word was selected. Is such a functionality possible with PhpStorm as well? If so, how can I achieve this?

Comment: Double click usually selects whole word (at least here on Windows) unless you have setting for "CamelHumps" words enabled. If you can avoid using mouse at all -- better use `Edit | Extend selection` (previously known as "Select word at caret" AFAIR).

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to get it done:

I've recorded a macro:

- click on a (random) word
- extend selection (ctrl-w)

And saved the macro.

After this, I assigned the shortkey ALT-leftmouse to it, and now I can select a whole word when clicking on it, if you hold down the alt key.

(I decided to keep the ctrl-mouselick to its original function)

Answer (score 0):

To select a word just double click the word.

ctrl-click is the Shortcut to go the the declaration of the word(function/variable).

There is a reference sheet and other documentation stuff to dig into:
https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/documentation/

Comment: I try to avoid to many mouseclicks, plus I'm used to ctrl-clicking on a word now :) It's a really quick way of selecting a word as well. Any idea if it can be done in phpstorm?